how to make a Scroll snap effect in react-virtuoso?
I'm trying to implement the Scroll snap effect in react. Scroll snap is when you scroll a little and it auto scrolls to the next card in the list.
In this example, react-virtuoso displays only the first few cards (due to overscan={{ main: 1000, reverse: 1000 }}):
'use client';

import React, { forwardRef, HTMLProps } from 'react';
import { Virtuoso } from 'react-virtuoso';

import { FeedCard, useGetProductsQuery } from '@/entities/product';

import { SHomeScreen } from './home-screen.styles';

const components = {
  List: forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>>(
    ({ style, children, ...props }, ref) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            overflow: 'scroll',
            scrollSnapType: 'y mandatory',
            height: '100vh',
            ...style,
          }}
          ref={ref}
          {...props}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  ),
  Item: forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>>(
    ({ style, children, ...props }, ref) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            scrollSnapAlign: 'start',
            ...style,
          }}
          ref={ref}
          {...props}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  ),
};

export function HomeScreen() {
  const { data, fetchNextPage } = useGetProductsQuery();

  return (
    <SHomeScreen>
      <Virtuoso
        useWindowScroll
        data={data || []}
        itemContent={(_, itemData) => <FeedCard {...itemData} />}
        components={components}
        overscan={{ main: 1000, reverse: 1000 }}
        endReached={() => {
          fetchNextPage();
        }}
      />
    </SHomeScreen>
  );
}

as soon as I remove overflow: scroll in the List component, everything starts working (Except Scroll snap)
